# Trouble accessing custom profile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add some custom identity profile information to my asp mvc 5 application, and am running into trouble. This is my first time using MVC or Identity (coming from Web Forms), and after hours of research, I'm still stumped.

I followed the guide at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx and added everything I should.

model

```
Models/IdentityModel.cs   

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

AccountViewModel

```
Models/AccountViewModel
...
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

I also modified the account controller and register view to ask for and save the new information. When registering, there are no issues, and my application properly saves the First, middle, and last names to dbo.AspNetUsers (I can see the data in SQL Server Management Studio).

However, I am totally unable to retrieve any of this information. I attempted to follow the guide by doing the following in a controller:

```
var currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var manager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

But then when I type "currentUser.", all I see is "AccessFailedCount, Claims, Email, EmailConfirmed" etc. Intellisense doesn't show anything related to first, middle, or last name. I attempted to just connect to dbo.AspNetUsers and pull stuff myself, but it doesn't seem to want to let me do that.

What am I doing wrong? My modified profile is saving properly, but I don't know how to access what it's saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access **UserManager** via **OwinContext**.

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext()
           .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
    }
}
```

Then you can call **UserManager.FindById** and access custom properties.

```
ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
string middleName = user.MiddleName;
```

Comment: Awesome! I had never heard of OwinContext before right now, but this code does exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for your help!